# HTML5 video on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html

I'm doing a little thingy with html5 video. I have a video which stops on certain points (predefined array with time points). When the video stops I display a box on the screen. The problem is that on the iPhone you watch the video on a special window. So is it possible with javascript to close that window when the video pauses?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've heard that you need to actually remove the video from the DOM once it has "ended"

I can't speak from experience though, good luck.